# How to make a Java project 'extendable' by developers?

Tags: java, design-patterns, development-environment

I'm working on a server engine, and I am not sure in what form to distribute it. It is quite modular and it uses interfaces/abstract classes.

Should it be:

- a library (no entry-point, write your own `main()` and call `new Server().setSomeHandler(myHandler).run()`)
- a binary (executable entrypoint with config file where you can inject JAR with handlers)
- something else?

Basically, the developer should be able to completely extend or change the way the server works. I don't like the idea of making it a library because it should be a platform by itself, a whole server system.

Comment: Look at frameworks that you use and enjoy using; what do they do?

Comment: @beresfordt The point is, this is not really a framework. It should be a server solution working by itself. I definitely want it to be opensource and well documented, but at the same time it should feel like an executable service and not just some code. OpenStack feels like that, it's a whole platform and it doesn't feel like a library, but it's really extendable.

Comment: Nothing's stopping you from doing more than one thing, but having a `Server` that I can instantiate multiple instances of my own is ideal. Having a predefined `main()` is just a perk.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann You bring up a very good point – sometimes the devs would like to extend so much that no entry point would allow doing so. So doing a library and a basic EntryPoint.java would be the best

Comment: @DavidEhrmann On the other hand, software like SmartFox give you a binary executable and only allow injecting .JAR's or .py's which means devs don't have to care about libs/server code and you may do it while the server is running but it's also restricting.

Comment: Maybe Java RMI helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing a programmatic way is more versatile than just an executable. And both ways aren't mutually exclusive. After all, even if a developer provides a handler, internally you probably still need to call something like the setter in your example to actually use that handler. Exposing that API shouldn't be too difficult. You could still provide a small launcher application that loads some config file and wraps it in some API calls, if that is needed.

The more important question would be, are there predefined extension points where developers can plug in their own implementations or is everything completely modular and exchangeable?

For a simple way to provide implementations of predefined interfaces, you can use the ServiceLoader/SPI mechanism. You can built a basic plug-in system with it.

If you want to create a platform, something like OSGi seems more appropriate. Here you could define APIs/SPIs for fine grained components/services. Developers could then provide their own modules that extend the server or even replace your default modules.

Comment: I want it to be friendly for non-programmers (no compile) and friendly for programmers (see source & docs, create own handlers). What would you suggest?

Comment: I think I would create a well documented library first, it seems like the most important part. After that, an executable that loads handlers with the ServiceLoader and uses the library to inject the handlers. The other approach using OSGI is way more complicated and probably not too friendly for programmers.